# UNIQUE constraint failed even after deleting the OneTone relation in Django

Tags: python, django

I've a `OneToOneField` in my Django models , and it gives me the error `UNIQUE constraint failed` even after remove it before trying to save ,, here is an example:

**models.py**

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    phone = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    salary = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    shift = models.OneToOneField(Shift, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='employee')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('employee_details', args=[str(self.id)])


class Shift(models.Model):
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=CASCADE)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.branch) + ' ( ' + str(self.start_time) + ' / ' + str(self.end_time) + ' )'
```

**forms.py**

```py
class AssignEmployeeToShift(forms.Form):
    employee = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.filter(shift__isnull=True), widget=forms.Select())
```

**views.py**

```py
class EmployeeAssignToShift(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    form_class = AssignEmployeeToShift
    template_name = 'back_office/employee_assign_to_shift.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('branch_details', args=[str(Shift.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk']).branch.id)])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeAssignToShift, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['current_shift'] = Shift.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        shift_object = get_object_or_404(Shift, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        employee_instance = form.cleaned_data['employee']
        employee_object = Employee.objects.filter(shift=shift_object)
        if employee_object.count() != 0:
            employee_object[0].shift = None
            employee_object[0].save()
            employee_instance.shift = shift_object
            employee_instance.save()
        else:
            employee_instance.shift = shift_object
            employee_instance.save()
        return super(EmployeeAssignToShift, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, as the error message suggests, at least two `Employee` share the same `Shift`.

Your `Shift` instance is already linked with an `Employee`. Since it's an `OneToOneField`, it means a Shift should be linked only with one Employee and vice-versa.

Comment: That is what meant to use `OneToOneField` ..and I have already avoided the duplication in the `def form_Valid()` part in the views ,,

Comment: Then check in your Django shell if the Shift isn't linked with an Employee yet